# Problems creating keyframes with low fps in blender

Tags: objects, blenderkit

[image]I'm starting to tinker a bit with blender development and I'm creating my first animations in blender through keyframes, but I'm having some problems when it comes to setting up the animations...

I have an intel i7 processor and a 3060 graphics card.

Generating a flat object, simple and indicating in tools like ocean and selecting a resolution of 30, when I generate keyframes does not exceed 0.20 fps, I understand that this is for configuration issues but I do not understand much how I can improve the performance or if you really need something more powerful to simulate the movement that I seek.

[image]

Comment: The resolution of ocean is to high even for your setup. For realtime animation it's better to use the value <15

Comment: Would you need a more powerful device? Okay, thank you very much for the recommendation on the value I should apply.

Comment: I don't have the opportunity to test ocean modifier on better setup. I tested it on mine 2070 Super which basicly has the same stats as yours 3060, and as I said <15 value was OK)

Comment: OK, perfect, thank you very much Yuri !!